# C++: Explanation for a Competitive Programming Tip

Tags: c++, optimization

On the DMOJ online judge, used for competitive programming, one of the tips for a faster execution time (C++) was to add this macro on top if the problem only requires unsigned integral data types to be read.

How does this work and what are the advantages and disadvantages of using this?

```
#define scan(x) do{while((x=getchar())<'0'); for(x-='0'; '0'<=(_=getchar()); x= (x<<3)+(x<<1)+_-'0');}while(0)
char _;
```

Source: https://dmoj.ca/tips/#cpp-io

Comment: What are your critetia for better/worse?

Comment: Expand the macro out and look at it. You know it reads unsigned ints, so figure out how. It's not terribly complicated. https://ideone.com/kOKdxU

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First let's reformat this a bit:

```
#define scan(dest) \
  do { \
    while((dest = getchar()) < '0'); \
    for(dest -= '0'; '0' <= (temp = getchar()); dest = (dest<<3) + (dest<<1) + temp - '0');
  } while(0)
char temp;
```

First, the outer `do{...}while(0)` is just to ensure proper parsing of the macro.  See [here](http://www.bruceblinn.com/linuxinfo/DoWhile.html) for more info.

Next, `while((dest = getchar()) < '0');` - this might as well just be `dest = getchar()` but it does some additional work by discarding any characters below (but not above) the `'0'` character.  This can be useful since whitespace characters are all "less than" the 0 character in ascii.

The meat of the macro is the `for` loop.  First, the initialization expression `dest -= '0'`, sets dest to the actual integer value represented by the character by taking advantage of the fact that the 0-9 characters in ascii encoding are adjacent and sequential.  So if the first character were `'5'` (value 53), subtracting `'0'` (value 48) results in the integer value `5`.

The condition statement, `'0' <= (temp = getchar())`, does several things - first, it gets the next character and assigns it to `temp`, then checks to see if it is greater than or equal to the `'0'` character (so will fail on whitespace).

As long as the character is a numeral (or at least equal to `'0'`), the increment expression is evaluated. `dest = (dest<<3) + (dest<<1) + temp - '0'` - the `temp - '0'` expression does the same adjustment as before from ascii to numeric value, and the shifts and adds are just an obscure way of multiplying by 10.  In other words, it is equivalent to `temp -= '0'; dest = dest * 10 + temp;`.  Multiplying by 10 and adding the next digit's value is what builds the final value.

Finally, `char temp;` declares the temporary character storage for use in subsequent macro invocations in the program.

As far as why you'd use it, I'm skeptical that it would provide any measurable benefit compared to something like `scanf` or `atoi`.

Comment: Nice answer. I think that for more advanced programers it would be interesting to understand 1. Why are they using shifts instead of multiplying (guessing it is an old habbit of code optimization for older processors), and 2. Why is this better than scanf/cin.

Comment: @ZivS Using shifts instead of multiply is very poor advice.  When multiplying by a constant, compilers can do that transformation if it is helpful (but will be hard-pushed to undo it if it is not).

Answer (score 1):

What this does is it reads a number character by character with a bunch of premature optimizations. See @MooseBoys' answer for more details.

About its advantages and disadvantages, I don't see any benefit to using this at all. Stuff like `(x<<3)+(x<<1)` which is equal to `x * 10` are optimizations that should be done by the compiler, not you.

As far as I know, `cin` and `cout` is fast enough for all competitive programming purposes especially if you disable syncing with stdio. I've been using it since I started competitive programming and never had any problems.

Also, my own testing shows `cin` and `cout` isn't slower than C I/O, despite the popular belief. You can try testing the performance of this yourself. Make sure you have optimizations enabled.

Apparently, some competitive programmers focus way too much on stuff like fast I/O when their algorithm is the thing that matters most.